# 500 error on deployed django app with debug set to False

Tags: python, django, heroku

I know this has been asked before but ive done everything recommended in other posts but i am still encountering the issue.

I've added necessary allowed hosts
set up postgres so that I don't use sqlite in production
whitenoise set up
and there's no issue with my static files previously when I ran heroku logs --tail it showed variable errors since i was using sqlite but i resolved that by setting up postgres and running migrate so
all seems fine now so I'm stuck

output from log

```
2020-09-27T17:17:09.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-09-27T17:17:18.450683+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.16.178.50 - - [27/Sep/2020:17:17:18 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 145 "http://zersh.shop/users/seller_reg/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:81.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/81.0"
2020-09-27T17:17:18.451441+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=zersh.shop request_id=c7568fc0-74d7-466b-b309-e9dacb26842f fwd="154.231.163.135" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=833ms status=500 bytes=577 protocol=http
```

urls project level

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf.urls import handler404


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('users/', include('user.urls')),
    path('users/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    path('', include('pages.urls')),
    path('store/', include('store.urls')),
    #path("djangorave/", include("djangorave.urls", namespace="djangorave")),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)


#error handlers
handler404 = 'store.views.error_404'
#handler500 = 'store.views.my_custom_error_view'
```

settings

```
import dj_database_url
import dotenv
import django_heroku
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# This is new:
dotenv_file = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ".env")
if os.path.isfile(dotenv_file):
    dotenv.load_dotenv(dotenv_file)

DEBUG = False 

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['example.herokuapp.com']



# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # my apps
    'user.apps.UserConfig',
    'store.apps.StoreConfig',
    'pages.apps.PagesConfig',

    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic', 
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',

    # 3rd party apps
    'crispy_forms',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    #'djangorave',

    #providors
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'zershecom.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'store.context_processors.categories_processor',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'zershecom.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases


DATABASES = {}
DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=600)



# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/


AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'user.CustomUser'

#LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
#LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'


# media configurations
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

# django-crispy-forms config
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'

# django-allauth config
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_REDIRECT = 'home'

ACCOUNT_SESSION_REMEMBER = True


SITE_ID = 1

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
)

ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_PASSWORD_ENTER_TWICE = False
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'username'
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True


STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_root')
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'


LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
             'level': os.getenv('DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL', 'DEBUG'),
        },
    },
}

django_heroku.settings(locals())

options = DATABASES['default'].get('OPTIONS', {})
options.pop('sslmode', None)
```

pipfile

```
[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[dev-packages]

[packages]
django = "*"
pillow = "*"
mysqlclient = "*"
django-allauth = "*"
django-crispy-forms = "*"
gunicorn = "*"
psycopg2-binary = "*"
whitenoise = "*"
python-dotenv = "*"
django-heroku = "*"

[requires]
python_version = "3.8"
```

Procfile

```
web: gunicorn zershecom.wsgi --log-file -
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not providing information about your requirements.txt and procfile, i'm sure you can check those files and double check that you wrote out all the neccesary information.

Comment: Im using pipenv so i have a pipfile instead let me share my packages and procfile

Answer (score 0):

I think using a database URI will be a smarter option. Get to your app on heroku and get the database URI. https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/09/how-to-deploy-django-applications-on-heroku.html